# Format cells in column based on first cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I'd like to create a table with checkboxes:

- one column for one day, date in the first cell
- if checkbox is true = fill green
- if checkbox is false and date in the first cell is today or
  earlier = fill cell red

I've found how to do that for specific column, e.g. for F column:

- Green: `Text is exactly FALSE`
- Red: `Custom formula is =(TODAY()-F1>0)+FALSE`

But when I try to create conditional formatting for multiple columns - it is still based on F1 value

How to make it work for all columns based on the first cell of the same column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

green color custom formula:

```
=F$2=TRUE
```

---

red color custom formula:

```
=(F$2=FALSE)*(F$1<=TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

---

### EXAMPLE 2:

green color custom formula:

```
=A2=TRUE
```

red color custom formula

```
=(A2=FALSE)*(A$1<=TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

Comment: good idea. but how to define formula that can format all the A:G columns without setting up every column separately
[example](http://prntscr.com/pd00bl)